# Curl encoding of SERP

Tags: curl, encoding, utf-8

```
    $url = "https://www.google.pl/search?q=agawa+korzenie&oq=agawa+korzenie";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"); //   "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array(
     //'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
     'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
    ));
   $icerik = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $icerik;
```

The encoding of response is invalid. Characters such as ś get translated to ? sign. How can I overcome that issue?

Comment: how are you running the script?

Answer (score 0):

if what you say is really true, then it's a problem with the server, not with curl. but most likely, it's not a problem with the server either, it's probably a problem with how you view the result. here are my theories, ranging from most likely, to least likely:

1: you view the result in a web browser, you are not supplying the `encoding` parameter in the `Content-Type:` header, and the browser identify the content as HTML4, where the default charset is `ISO-8859-1`, and thus renders it as `ISO-8859-1`, which doesn't support `ś`, and the browser turns the unrenderable characters into `?`. the fix is to change the Content-Type header into `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf8`

2: same as above, but your server is actually supplying the wrong content-type header, eg `Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`, the fix is the same as above.

3: the server is storing data in a sql db (like mysql) with the saving charset set to `ISO-8859-1` (or something close to it), and then the db replace invalid characters with `?` (i've seen this many times in the past, but not in recent years), in which case the server code must be fixed. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/1067003

4: you run PHP in a terminal which doesn't support unicode characters. the solution is to switch to a better terminal. (not very likely, but hey, xterm is still around, and still has a no-unicode version, you could be using normal xterm)

5: the server really is running some version of `$response=str_replace($response,'ś','?');echo $response;` ... highly unlikely, but not impossible, which must also be fixed on the server side. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/1067003

lastly, protip, you're confused, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER is headers curl send to the target url in the request, when you set `Content-Type` with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, you set the Content-Type for the request body of the curl request. but because you're not using CURLOPT_INFILE, nor are you using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, there is no request body at all, and thus there shouldn't be any content-type header in the request, get rid of it. you were probably looking for the `header()` function, eg `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`, which will send that header to the browser.